# Error when loading sdk while opening eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have installed all packages on Android SDK manager. And this is the first time i am using eclipse. So I have created a virtual device too. Now while i am trying to start my works on eclipse its shows some errors. I have tried many things can't solve this. Below is my error. Please anyone help me to resolve this.

```
[2015-11-06 20:49:05 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:

Error: Error parsing C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
[2015-11-06 20:49:13 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Shakir\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2015-11-06 20:49:13 - appcompat_v7]
```

Comment: Just use Android Studio. How to:http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having this question after I defined my own skin for an AVD according to this site https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html. I'v searched for this problem for quite a while without finding more workable answer than deleting the 'd:skin' line in the problem file "devices.xml"(This'll DISABLE your own skin defination for the AVD).

Every time I'm about to start my work, firstly I remove (if not, the AVD can't be started.) the postfix ".old" which is added to the "devices.xml" by Eclipse when it's started and finds the so-called error which you've seen, next, I start the AVD which uses the "devices.xml" containing my own skin defination, at last I start Eclipse. Though it still warns about this error, I just ignore it before finding out the final solution.

In my openion, if you don't want to do special defination for the skin of your AVD, you can just try the "deleting".